# How to extract type parameters from type alias & type arguments from generic instance?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Given this:

```
type Qux<A, B> = {}
type Bar<A, B> = Qux<A, B> & B
export type Foo = Bar<1, 2>
```

How can we extract with the TypeScript compiler API by traversing the exports dynamically that there is a `Bar` alias generic whose parameters are `A` and `B` and that there is a `Qux` alias generic  whose parameters are `A` and `B`.

It shjould also be extracted that `Foo` is an instance of `Bar` and its type arguments are `1` and `2`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here. Can you give an example of what these types look like and what you are trying to build?

Comment: The types look like as they are in the code block. The context of what is trying to be built is a documentation generator.